# hover didnt work on ios

Tags: html, ios, css, hover

I have an image hover and it works great on android but it didn't work on ios
this is my html:

```
<div class="hovereffect hover7">
  <%= cl_image_tag("wet.jpg", :crop=>"scale", :height=>400, :quality=>90, :class => "img-responsive line") %>
  <div class="center-overlay">
    <p class="info-hover">RUBATO</p>
    <p>Jazz</p>
    <p>Colima</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my scss:

```
  .hovereffect img{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: none;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .hovereffect:hover img{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
  .hovereffect a, .hovereffect p{
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  }
  .hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,5);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

I don't know why is not working if is just css
it works perfectly on adroid

Comment: Since you can't actually 'hover' on a touch device, some devices treat the first click on something as a hover (if hover states are available). Some don't. Generally speaking, you shouldn't rely on 'hover' effects on touch devices.

Comment: ain't you compiling scss to css before ?

Comment: yes im using rails, @jack but why it works on android

Comment: Most android devices include hover state on mousedown event. May be ios safari browser doesn't include this. You could better get away by adding  `hovereffect` class with jquery on mousedown event.

Comment: Like I said - devices behave differently. Android devices might bind that first tap to 'hover', while iOS might not.

Comment: @jack and there is no way to use focus or something like that?

Comment: There are some hacky ways to force this (check out the Related questions to the right of this one) but first make sure you really *need* this. People aren't typically expecting hover behaviors on touch devices - when you tap a link, you expect to go to it. If this is just a cosmetic effect, I'd say don't worry about making it work everywhere. On the other hand, if it's an important part of your content - where you really need to show that hovered version of the image for the page to be complete - then go ahead and look into using javascript to make this work. (CSS alone won't do it.)

Comment: yeah i know but its important cause when you hover it, shows the artist name and info